# Put personal files/folders on Windows 10 USB boot media

Tags: usb, windows-10, windows-installation, bootable-media

I made a Windows 10 USB boot/install media using the Windows 10 media creation tool. There are still 10 GB free on the USB and my question is - can I put personal files/folder on the USB without it interfering with the the USB's intended purpose (installing Windows 10)?

I'm assuming so, that the Windows installation software will just ignore other folders, but thought I would ask it here before I screw something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will ignore them. My all-in-one USB drive contains Visual Studio installer and various toolkit, yet it still boot and install Windows 10 successfully.