# How to edit Windows Install Disk Boot to run batch script?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, batch

I have a batch script that lets me recover files from a crashed computer. It is put on a usb for the Windows 10 Installation Disk (made by the media creation tool here). Is there any way I could edit the boot so that it runs the batch script automatically instead of my having to find it with shift+F10? Any searches I entered on google came up with "starting a batch file on *startup* instead of on *boot*, since those words are sort of interchangeable. Note this is not a duplicate of [Put personal files/folders on Windows 10 USB boot media](https://superuser.com/questions/969297/put-personal-files-folders-on-windows-10-usb-boot-media) since I am not trying to simply have the file on the drive, but start it with or instead of the Install executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest creating a windows PE bootable instead.

**Startnet.cmd**

You can add customized command-line scripts in Windows PE by using Startnet.cmd. By default, Windows PE includes a Startnet.cmd script located at %SYSTEMROOT%\System32 of your customized Windows PE image.

Comment: Is this what you're talking about here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/download-winpe--windows-pe ?

Comment: @MarkDodsons Looks like the right stuff.

Comment: This is the correct solution.  This is the same environment that the installation environment uses except you can customize it,

Comment: I've created the drive, but where could I put my batch file so that it would be accessible regardless of drive letters?

Comment: @MarkDodsons  You are supposed to rename it Startnet.cmd and place it in  the system32 folder overwriting the existing one.  In the batch file you are supposed to use %~dp0 to reference the drive letter.

Comment: Sorry @cybernard but where do I find the system32 folder. If I boot into it on a computer and move it there, it wouldn't save it on power off would it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: All the relavant files should be on or place on your USB stick in the correct folder.  When your system is booted into windows do you see a system32 folder on your memory stick?

Comment: Otherwise you may have to mount the wim file and add it to there.

Comment: theres no system32 on the drive. Where do I find the wim file? its mostly a bunch of aa-aa bg-BG folders with BOOT.mui files.

Comment: I can even unplug the boot drive and the system will continue to run fine

Comment: Also %~dp0 just gives the current cd on X:\, the drive is labeled E:\ .

Comment: do you have a wim file either boot.wim or install.wim or something else?

Comment: Yes there was a boot.wim in WinPE_amd64. I've mounted it and am adding files thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try the free version of
[NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/) to create your installation media.

The Features page says :

> **Application Integration**
>
> Easily integrate application installers, scripts, registry tweaks or
>   raw commands. Provide a silent switch and automatically
>   **run application installer post-setup**.

Comment: I'm reluctant to use this tool as I have heard people tell me of accidental critical damage.

Comment: NTLite has a good reputation, but there is a learning curve.

Comment: This would be partially for corporate use so the free version would not suffice. Still a good solution though.